# bluetooth not work for rpi3

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth

I am using Rpi3 bluetooth.
when I try to use bluetoothctl cmd, it returns

> No default controller available

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi # bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# power on
No default controller available

[bluetooth]# scan on
No default controller available

root@raspberrypi:/home/pi # cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.9.24-v7+ (dc4@dc4-XPS13-9333) (gcc version 4.9.3 (crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.22.0-88-g8460611) ) #993 SMP Wed Apr 26 18:01:23 BST 2017

root@raspberrypi:/home/pi # systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: **active (running)** since Sun 2017-06-11 00:15:03 CST; 11min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 1980 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─1980 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jun 11 00:15:03 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jun 11 00:15:03 raspberrypi bluetoothd[1980]: Bluetooth daemon 5.23
Jun 11 00:15:03 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jun 11 00:15:03 raspberrypi bluetoothd[1980]: Starting SDP server
Jun 11 00:15:03 raspberrypi bluetoothd[1980]: Bluetooth management interface 1.1
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: the os is latest debian jessie

Comment: Could you post the output of `show`?